# PayPal Website Payments Standard Security

Tags: security, paypal

I currently have a Website Payments Standard checkout process for purchasing recurring payments. WPS just use some inputs hidden to send all information to PayPal.
But it's very insecure because if you know HTML, you can change these inputs hidden at browser's developer tool and change the prices.
I chose WPS because it's simplest than the Express Checkout, and you don't need a API integration. 
So, someone had the same problem? There is a security way to use WPS?

Comment: Are you using a subscription button?

Comment: I'm not using subscription buttons because the amount and the period are dynamic. Using the PayPal buttons I have to set these informations previously.

Answer (score 0):

How are you using WPS? With the PayPal buttons? If so, you can create encrypted buttons when you log into your PayPal account. If you are using something else, let me know and I can look into it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm not using subscription buttons because the amount and the period are dynamic. Using the PayPal buttons I have to set these informations previously.

Comment: I'm using just the HTML variables (hidden inputs)

Comment: you can create an encrypted button within paypal, will this not work for you?